# Native query execution on Oracle database throws java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In my spring-boot project I use spring-data, Hibernate and Oracle as database.

I have entities `Message`, `User` and `SeenMessage`.

`Messaage` looks like:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "MESSAGES")
    public class Messages {
    
        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MARKET_MESSAGE_GENERATOR")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "MARKET_MESSAGE_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "MARKET_MESSAGE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
        private Long id;
    
        @Basic
        @Column(name = "PUBLISH_DATE")
        private Timestamp dateTime;
    
        @Basic
        @Column(name = "TITLE")
        private String title;
    
        @Lob
        @Nationalized
        @Column(name = "MESSAGE", columnDefinition="NCLOB NOT NULL")
        private String message;
 }
```

`User` looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USER_GENERATOR")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "USER_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "USERS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String userName;
}
```

and `SeenMessage` looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SEEN_MESSAGE")
public class SeenMessage {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEEN_MESSAGE_GENERATOR")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEEN_MESSAGE_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SEEN_MESSAGE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "SEEN_DATE")
    private Timestamp seenDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MESSAGE_ID")
    private Messages message;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user; 
}
```

Also on this table (`SEEN_MESSAGE`) I have unique constraint condition on pair of (`Message_Id`, `User_Id`)

And now the problem:

I have a simple REST API for getting message with its ID, when anyone calls this service I will return the requested message and also I will Insert a record in `seenMessage` table with `messageId` and `userId` and of course its time.

I do the second action(inserting in SeenMessage) in my service layer by calling a method from repository:

```
@Repository
public interface SeenMessageRepository extends JpaRepository<SeenMessage, Long> {

    @Query(value = "begin " +
            "insert into SEEN_MESSAGE(ID, MESSAGE_ID, USER_ID, SEEN_DATE) " +
            "values(seen_message_seq.nextval, :MId , :UId , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ); " +
            "exception " +
            "when dup_val_on_index THEN " +
            "RETURN; " +
            "end;", nativeQuery = true)
    void insertAndForget(Long MId, Long UId);
}
```

As you can see I have wrote a native query, and when I execute it on DBMS it will successfully executed, but when I call my API using Postman, query will execute and performs as I expect but also it throws an exception which is:

```
2021-10-26 11:12:50.385 ERROR 4848 --- [nio-1201-exec-2] c.a.b.o.exceptions.ExceptionTranslator   : -1

java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ResultRowProcessor.prepareForAutoDiscovery(ResultRowProcessor.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.preprocessResultSet(Loader.java:2343)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2299)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2843)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2825)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2657)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2652)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1169)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1604)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.insertAndForget(Unknown Source)
```

And maybe it is good to say that I wrote this query and did not use a simple Insert query, because in that case I needed to check Duplicate myself(if i did not check the duplicate I may face `UniqueconstraintViolationException`) with another database call which is extra in my opinion, so I wrote this one.

Can someone tell me the reason of this error??

why it executes on DBMS with no error but in my application it causes an error??

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to put `@Modifying` annotation over my repository method as below:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "BEGIN " +
        "INSERT INTO SEEN_MESSAGE(ID, MESSAGE_ID, USER_ID, SEEN_DATE) " +
        "VALUES(seen_message_seq.nextval, :MId , :UId , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ); " +
        "EXCEPTION " +
        "WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN " +
        "RETURN;" +
        "END;", nativeQuery = true)
void insertAndForget(Long MId, Long UId);
```

also I needed to open a `TRANSACTION` in my service layer, for this purpose I put `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` over my method in service layer which calls my repository method.